# Ruby on rails forms, partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial-views

I have index page:

```
        <div>
          <%= render :partial => "ev_calendar" %>
        </div>
        <% Project.events.each do |event| %>
        <%= link_to l(event.published_at, :format => "%d.%m.%Y"), event %>
        <div>
          <%= event.description %>
        </div>
       <% end %>
```

ev_calendar:

```
...
<%= day %>
...
```

day - it's a day oncalendar, only a number. How can I make this da like link, after clicking on this link - my page reloaded and first example-code show events only for this day (by created_at attribute).? plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<%= link_to day, your_path_to_action(:day => day) %>
```

then you can catch `:day` parameter in params[:day]. In action you can verify this parameter and do something like this:

```
Project.events.where(["DAY(created_at) = ?", params[:day]])
```